# Enforce a standard interface for a number of C libraries

Tags: c, interface, reusability

In OO languages, we have ways to enforce a standardisation of interfaces across the number of libraries:

```
   Interface
      |------Implementation A
      |
      \------Implementation B
```

I have thoughts to do something like this:

```
  Interface.h
      |------Implementation A.c
      |
      \------Implementation B.c
```

where Interface.h contains:

- `functionStandard_A()`
- `functionStandard_B()`

What would be the best practice in C to achieve something like this?

Comment: C does not have facilities for enforcing interface implementations.  The best you can do is provide a coherent API.

Comment: I would go with function pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "interface" in C can be created by defining a `struct` of function pointers. Each "concrete implementation" would present itself through an instance of this `struct`, having initialised the function pointers within it to point to the functions within that implementation.

For example, imagine creating an modem driver interface so that different C modem drivers have a standard set of functions. I use modem drivers because they're a good example from an application I happen to be working on now.

Example of interface:

```
typedef struct modem_interface
{
    void (*start_call)(void);
    void (*hang_up)(void);
    ...
}
```

You might have two different modem drivers, `modem_A.c` and `modem_B.c`, each with their own functions to handle starting a call, hanging up a call, and other operations. Each driver creates an instance of `modem_interface` and inialises it so that the function pointers point to its functions.

For example, within modem_A.c:

```
...
modem_interface modem_A_interface;
modem_interface.start_call = &modem_A_start_call; 
...
```

Somewhere else in the application, you might grab a pointer to modem A's 'interface' `struct` and call standard functions ("methods") on it as they are defined originally in `modem_interface`:

```
...
modem_A->start_call();
modem_A->hang_up();
...
```

This way, you can have any number of modem drivers, but the application can work with any of them simply through a `modem_interface` pointer. For example:

```
void application_starts_a_call( modem_interface* required_modem )
{
    required_modem->start_call();
    ...
}


// elsewhere:
application_starts_a_call( &modem_A );
application_starts_a_call( &modem_B );
```

Quickly typed out before I rush out of the door so corrections welcomed. Hope it illustrates the concept well enough.